# How to handle Header click event in DataGrid in the context of MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, datagrid

I know how to handle Header click event in DataGrid WPF using code-behind approach:

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="columnHeader_Click" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
</DataGrid>
```

However, I would like to handle this event in the context of MVVM. I've tried to handle by `System.Windows.Interactivity`, but I cannot figure out what I should write inside of `EventName`:

```
<DataGrid>
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="What event can I use?"
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

I've seen events such as `ColumnReordered`, `ColumnReordering`, but it is not applicable.

How can I handle Header click event in DataGrid WPF in the context of MVVM?

Comment: @downvoter What is the reason to down vote?

Comment: Surely its the name of the event. So "Click"

Comment: @CathalMF there is no such event!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx here are all the events. Pick one.

Comment: You can't set an interaction click event on a datagrid header guys, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the trigger in the header style. Interaction triggers and behaviours can't ordinarily be set in a style because the TriggerCollection and BehaviorCollection classes are sealed, so you can't declare them in XAML. However, user vspivak posted [a workaround for this on the wordpress site](https://vspivak.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/using-system-windows-interactivity-behaviors-and-actions-in-wpfsilverlight-styles/) which basically creates its own lists and keeps them synchronized with those in the Interaction lists:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace YourApplication
{
    /// <summary>
    /// <see cref="FrameworkTemplate"/> for InteractivityElements instance
    /// <remarks>Subclassed for forward compatibility, perhaps one day <see cref="FrameworkTemplate"/> </remarks>
    /// <remarks>will not be partially internal</remarks>
    /// </summary>
    public class InteractivityTemplate : DataTemplate
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Holder for interactivity entries
    /// </summary>
    public class InteractivityItems : FrameworkElement
    {
        private List<Behavior> _behaviors;
        private List<System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase> _triggers;

        /// <summary>
        /// Storage for triggers
        /// </summary>
        public List<System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase> Triggers
        {
            get
            {
                if (_triggers == null)
                    _triggers = new List<System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase>();
                return _triggers;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Storage for Behaviors
        /// </summary>
        public List<Behavior> Behaviors
        {
            get
            {
                if (_behaviors == null)
                    _behaviors = new List<Behavior>();
                return _behaviors;
            }
        }

        #region Template attached property

        public static InteractivityTemplate GetTemplate(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (InteractivityTemplate)obj.GetValue(TemplateProperty);
        }

        public static void SetTemplate(DependencyObject obj, InteractivityTemplate value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(TemplateProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TemplateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Template",
            typeof(InteractivityTemplate),
            typeof(InteractivityItems),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(InteractivityTemplate), OnTemplateChanged));

        private static void OnTemplateChanged(
            DependencyObject d,
            DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            InteractivityTemplate dt = (InteractivityTemplate)e.NewValue;
#if(!SILVERLIGHT)
            dt.Seal();
#endif
            InteractivityItems ih = (InteractivityItems)dt.LoadContent();
            BehaviorCollection bc = Interaction.GetBehaviors(d);
            System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerCollection tc = Interaction.GetTriggers(d);

            foreach (Behavior behavior in ih.Behaviors)
                bc.Add(behavior);

            foreach (System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerBase trigger in ih.Triggers)
                tc.Add(trigger);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

With this in place it's a simple matter of applying it to the ColumnHeaderStyle:

```
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="local:InteractivityItems.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <local:InteractivityTemplate>
                        <local:InteractivityItems>
                            <local:InteractivityItems.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click" >
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.YourCommand,
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </local:InteractivityItems.Triggers>
                        </local:InteractivityItems>
                    </local:InteractivityTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
```

Bit kludgy, but it works.